# Get DropDownList selection from GridView on button press

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.NET GridView that has four columns.  The first three are typical BoundField elements bound to a DataTable.  The forth is a TemplateField element that I create a DropDownList in on the OnRowCreated event for the GridView.

What I'm attempting to do is walk down the data source for the GridView when a button is pressed.  I really just need to get the values for columns one and four of each row.  The first three columns have data as expected but the forth is displaying as empty.  Is this because it wasn't a part of the DataTable originally?  Is there any way to get the value for each drop down as I've described it, or will I need to rework this so each drop down list is a part of the DataTable?

Comment: Why you create the dropdown on RowCreated event? can't you just throw it on the ASPX? Or there is any conditional logic

Comment: The drop down is inside the TemplateField on the aspx page.  I'm populating the values on RowCreated.  Not sure if that answers your question or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer online.  It was something I'm surprised was actually the answer.  Instead of trying to populate the drop down on RowCreated, you need to do it on RowDataBound.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1540911/3753726.aspx